# Javascript Form Validation, multiple functions on a single button not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm working on a form validation project that requires multiple input fields connected to a single submit button. I more or less figured the button out, but I'm having an issue getting the functions themselves to work properly. I currently only have three of the eleven fields typed up for testing, but what the page should do is let you know which fields are invalid when there is nothing filled out in them (changing text/background colors, message below, etc).

The issue I'm having is that when the requirements for the first field (Gift Card Number) are met, it acts as though there isn't any issues anywhere, regardless of whether or not the other input fields (First name, Last name) have been filled. They all seem to function correctly if none of the fields are filled, but my concern is that the functions seem to be firing in order and first one to work negates all the ones after (for example, Gift Card prevents First and Last, First prevents Last, etc).

Any ideas where I've gone wrong here? I'll include my html and my javascript. (Yes, I know the html is a bit ugly, I plan to move the material over to a div table later, just trying to get it to function for now) Any help appreciated as always!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr id="rONE">
                <td><h4>Gift Card Amount</h4>
                    <form name="giftForm" onsubmit="return validateGiftCard()" method="post" id="GiftCardForm">
                    <input type="text" name="giftInput">

                    <h5 id="giftMessage"></h5></td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" />
                <td></td>
                </tr>
               </form>

                <tr id="rTWO-1">
                <td><h4>Recipient's name</h4>   
                    </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="rTWO-2">
                <td>
                    <form name="firstForm" onsubmit="return validateRecipient()" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="firstInput">
                    <br>
                    <h4>First</h4>
                </form>
                </td>
                <td><form name="lastForm" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="lastInput">
                    <br>
                    <h4>Last</h4></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><h5 id="recipientMessage"></h5></td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>

                <button type="submit" id="btn" form="GiftCardForm" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </body>
        <footer>
            <script src="Form Validation.js"></script>
        </footer>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    validateGiftCard();
    validateRecipient();
});


function validateGiftCard() {
    valid = true;
    if ( document.giftForm.giftInput.value == "" )
    {
        giftMessage.innerHTML = "This field is required";
        document.getElementById("rONE").style.backgroundColor="#fff7f7"
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}


function validateRecipient() {
    valid = true;
    if ( document.firstForm.firstInput.value == "" )
    {
        recipientMessage.innerHTML = "This field is required";
        document.getElementById("rTWO-1").style.backgroundColor="#fff7f7"
        document.getElementById("rTWO-2").style.backgroundColor="#fff7f7"
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var v1 = validateGiftCard();
  var v2 = validateRecipient();
  console.log(v1, v2);
  if (!v1 || !v2)
    e.preventDefault();
});


function validateGiftCard() {
  valid = true;
  if (document.giftForm.giftInput.value == "") {
    giftMessage.innerHTML = "This field is required";
    document.getElementById("rONE").style.backgroundColor = "#fff7f7"
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
}


function validateRecipient() {
  valid = true;
  if (document.firstForm.firstInput.value == "") {
    recipientMessage.innerHTML = "This field is required";
    document.getElementById("rTWO-1").style.backgroundColor = "#fff7f7"
    document.getElementById("rTWO-2").style.backgroundColor = "#fff7f7"
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="rONE">
      <td>
        <h4>Gift Card Amount</h4>
        <form name="giftForm" onsubmit="return validateGiftCard()" method="post" id="GiftCardForm">
          <input type="text" name="giftInput">

          <h5 id="giftMessage"></h5>
        </form>
      </td>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" />
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rTWO-1">
      <td>
        <h4>Recipient's name</h4>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rTWO-2">
      <td>
        <form name="firstForm" onsubmit="return validateRecipient()" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="firstInput">
          <br>
          <h4>First</h4>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form name="lastForm" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="lastInput">
          <br>
          <h4>Last</h4>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5 id="recipientMessage"></h5>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" id="btn" form="GiftCardForm" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I'm missing the && between the two functions! Would I use '&&' if there were several more functions or is that only for two? 

(edit) the first one actually doesn't fire off the second function at all now.

ALSO the second leaves me right back at square one, if I fill out the first item then it doesn't register the other two as incomplete.

Comment: More importantly :), you are missing `return` from the event handler.

Comment: And I would go for the second method - attaching functions as separate event hadlers.

Comment: Hmm, the third one doesn't work at all, and Visual Studio Code pops up with a few errors are typing it in for which it has no suggestions for fixes.

Comment: The third was missing `);` at the end.

Comment: Hmm, strangely it works perfectly fine in the snippet when I run it, but when I save it and open it up in a browser I get the same results I was originally having with with not validating things correctly. This is frustrating...